# Regular expression in python: matching a number as a variable

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to use the "re" library to match strings to those I need.

For example, I have a for loop like below and I want to find files which they end based on the loop number:

```
for ind in range(10):
    file_name = re.match(r'^abc.*\.\d{ind}', s)
```

but I think this is not a correct way, since ind is a variable?

For example, as a result I want to find these files:

```
> ind==1 -> abc1     ind==2 -> abc2       ind==3 -> abc3
```

I appreciate if you tell me the correct way to write this part of code.

Comment: Did you try using concatenation instead?

Comment: @CertainPerformance how can I do it?

Comment: Do you want to find something like `\d{3}` (number of repetition) or exactly `abc.*3`?

Comment: I wonder if your code is `f'^abc.*\.\d{ {ind} }'` . btw This syntax applies to versions after 3.6 (include)

Answer (score 0):

(Edited)

Placing a variable name in the string will not automatically replace the value for you. What you want to do is to `format` a string.

```
for ind in range(10):
    file_name = re.match(r'^abc.*\.{}'.format(ind), s)
```

If this is a bit confusing, you can also use the old syntax

```
re.match(r'^abc.*\.%d' % ind, s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
r'^abc.*[' + str(ind) + r']'
```

The token you used is incorrect. `{x}` is meant to repeat the preceding pattern by x number of times. Therefore `\d{ind}` basically indicates that your file would end with `ind` number of digits and not the number itself.

`[ind]` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on python36 or later

```
for ind in range(10):
    print(f'^abc.*\.\d{ {ind} }')
```